# sed: -e expression #1, char 5: unterminated `s' command

Tags: sed

I'm learning SED and I saw this sed substitution example. It's supposed to replace the first lowercase t as uppercase in each new line.:

```
$ sed 's/t/T' text-01.txt
  sed: -e expression #1, char 5: unterminated `s' command
```

Contents of file:

```
 $ cat text-01.txt
   10 tiny toes
   this is that
   5 funny 0
   one two three
   tree twice
```

It's not the end of the world though, since I can just output into a new file:

```
cat text-01.txt | sed 's/t/T/' > text-02.txt
```

But what am I supposed to do if I want to edit the original file?

Answer (score 1):

The commands aren't the same, the closing `/` is missing in the first one:

```
#                           v
                  sed 's/t/T' text-01.txt
cat text-01.txt | sed 's/t/T/' > text-02.txt
#                           ^
```

Comment: *sigh* Thanks for the quick correction